# Rsync with hard links very slow compared to rclone

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, sftp

I'm using a self made docker to sync files between two machines.

Inside the docker a sftp-folder is mounted using sshfs.

I always used rclone to sync the files:

`rclone sync --create-empty-src-dirs -v /mnt/sftp/backup/ /mnt/local/ --bwlimit $backup_bwlimit --log-file /config/logs/sftp-$date.log --stats 120s`

If no files changed this took only a few minutes to complete. There a like a 100k files, in total about 2,5TB of data.

Now I tried to use rsync:

`rsync -avq --stats --delete --log-file $logs_folder"rsync-"$today".log" --bwlimit $backup_bwlimit --link-dest=$dest_folder$last_backup $sftp_folder $dest_folder$today`

It so far took over 7 hours just for about 10.000 files, just for "building file list".

There are no files transferred over the network, but rsync hard links a new file about every 5 seconds in the destination directory. It uses the last backup to create hard links from.

Anybody got a clue what the problem could be here

Comment: I am not familiar with rclone: does your rclone command also make hard links to a previous backup? If no, you should compare also to a more classical rsync command without the `--link-dest` option, to be sure that this is the culprit. 
It also looks like your backup folder is on the local machine, right?

Comment: Does `rclone` copy metadata such as file modification time (mtime)? If not, `rsync` will have assumed the target files are all out of date and will be busy recopying them in their entirety. If you can give `rsync` access to the remote server rather than just the filesystem over `sshfs` you'll get a significant increase in efficiency.

Comment: Another thought, do `rclone` and `rsync` use the same units for `--bwlimit`? I'm not familiar with `rclone`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end it turned out that the file permissions were treated different between rsync and rclone and rsync created copies of all files (that haven't changed otherwise) from the local folder to change the permissions in the new folder.

Comment: If possible, try using `--delete-before` or `--no-inc-recursion`. With the default incremental recursion mode, `rsync` is often too happy to retransmit hardlinked files multiple times. (This is not a bug, the default mode is simply optimized for different use case.)